# Cannot instantiate inner class

Tags: java

That is my code:

```
public class A {
    int age;

    void Do() {
        System.out.println("...");
    }

    class B extends A {
    }

    public static void  main(String[] args) {
        B b=new B();
    }
}
```

error at:

```
new B();
```

Why? Why it is not right?

Comment: because your class B is inner class to A. And you have recursive relation in your case.

Comment: So you should make B static

Comment: For more information see java doc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Comment: An inner class always has an outer class instance to be an inner class of. `B` is an inner class but you haven't provided an instance of `A`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You declared `B` as an inner class of `A`, so you can't instantiate it without supplying an instance of the enclosing class `A`.

You can move the definition of B outside A to make your code work :

```
class B extends A
{

}

public class A
{
    int age;

    void Do()
    {
     System.out.println("...");
    }

    public static void  main(String[]args)
    {
        B b = new B();
    }
}
```

Or you can leave the class structure as is, but create an instance of A in order to create an instance of B :

```
B b = new A().new B();
```